# get path for my current .exe ( Based only on its name )

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

```
string productName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
productName = "myapp.exe";
if (!File.Exists(productName)) {
    MessageBox.Show("your message", "window title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);   
} else {
    //do nothing
}
```

I want this message box to show if I opened my application on whatever directory its in or current directory.

But then the logic of my app is that it copies itself to another directory with different name. so when i open it again i dont want this message box to appear. I know its a stupid logic but its a competition in my college I need to finish.
also I tried System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location; but everytime I open the app the message box appear and thats not what I wanted

Comment: Currently you are reassigning `productName`, you need to store path of `"Piriform.exe"`, using `Path.Combine()`, Like `string productName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Piriform.exe") ;`

Comment: thanks for helping me i appreciate it. this really worked for me and like what i wanted <3

Comment: @mariejose, I added my answer with a detailed description. If this works for you then kindly accept my answer by green tick

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `productName` twice,

1. With base directory
2. With your `.exe` name.

Instead of assignment, you need to combine the base directory with `.exe` name to get full path of the `"myapp.exe"` file, using `Path.Combine()` method.

Like,

```
string productName =  Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "myapp.exe");
if(!File.Exists(productName))
{
   MessageBox.Show("your message", "window title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information); 
}
else
{ 
   //Your code goes here
}
```

MSDN: [Path.Combine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-6.0)